# Does the definition of sample standard deviation require the subtraction of quantities of different units?

Tags: statistics

The sample standard deviation formula is
$$
S=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2}.
$$
For instance, if the $X_i$ has units *dollars* and the $n$ term has units *hours*, then the mean quantity has units *$ per hour*. How can the subtraction operation occur despite the difference in units?

Comment: This is not clear. What exactly is the  random variable $X$?  From your units I'd have guessed that $X_i$ was the number of dollars attached to a sampled hour $i$.  In which case the units for $X_i$ would be dollars per hour.  $n$ should just be a sample number.  But maybe you have some other scenario in mind?

Comment: $n$ has no units. It is just the number of samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X_i$ has units of dollars then so does $\bar X$ since $n$ is a dimensionless quantity.  It follows that $X_i-\bar X$ has units of dollars and $(X_i-\bar X)^2$ has units of dollars-squared so that the variance $S^2$ has units of dollars-squared.

Taking the square root implies $S$ will indeed have units of dollars.

If we look at the population standard deviation
$$
\sigma=\sqrt{\mathsf E(X-\mu)^2},
$$
this becomes more evident since $X$ and $\mu$ have units of dollars so $\mathsf E(X-\mu)^2$ has units of dollars-squared and thus $\sigma$ has units of dollars.